# c getaddrinfo no such host is known

Tags: c, sockets, networking, http-headers

I'm trying to use getaddrinfo by giving it the http(s) prefix and it doesn't look up the host correctly. How can i fix the problem. I want to look up https://www.google.com but the `gai_strerror()` returns "No such host is known", it works okay for www.google.com on port 80.

This is part of the code I'm using for the getaddrinfo() part:

```
// The GET request I pose to download the webpage
char *send_buf="GET / \r\n";

// i tried three different urls apparently changing the value in the
// value in the variable in my code, it only works for 'www.google.com'
const char *URL="https://www.google.com";
const char *URL="http://www.google.com";
const char *URL="www.google.com";

if( ( status=getaddrinfo(URL, PORT, &hints, &res) )!=0 )
{
    printf("%s\n", gai_strerror(status));
    exit(1);
}
```

I'm trying to download the webpage using winsock2 and when i use www.google.com, it gives me a 302 Moved message and I'd like to download the actual webpage without using any external libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give either the IP address or the hostname of the desired host. If you give a hostname then it will be converted into its respective IP address(es). A hostname should be in this form only:
`"www.example.domain_name"`. Do not include `"http://"` or `"https://"`.
That is a property of the URL that includes the hostname, it is not part of the hostname itself.

To download the HTML for `https://www.google.com`, you have to lookup the IP for `www.google.com`, then connect to that IP on port 443 (the default HTTPS port), then negotiate an SSL/TLS encryption session, and then finally send an HTTP `GET` request for the `/` document.

It is not wise to implement SSL/TLS encryption by hand. Use a library, such as OpenSSL, or Microsoft's own CryptoAPI, on top of your existing socket code. Alternatively, don't use socket APIs directly at all, use an HTTP/S library, such as Microsoft's own WinInet/WinHTTP API, or a library like libcurl, to handle all of the details for you.

Comment: then how can i download the html of the website?
since google.com gives me a 302 moved response

Comment: If you have recieved 302 response then you can use this link [http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E302.html](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E302.html) to fix your error.

Comment: @demogorgon a 302 response is an HTTP redirect. The fact that you get an HTTP redirect means you successful connected to an HTTP/S server and received a valid response to your request. The redirect is simply telling you to send your request to a different URL specified in the responses `Location` header. Parse the new URL and repeat the request using the new hostname/port/path as needed. Repeat as needed until no more redirects are received.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, if you'd be kind enough as to show this to me in code :), in addition, I know of the libraries but I do this purely for educational and extremely curious purposes